# Association with alias "alias" not exist on Model - Sequelize include error

Tags: node.js, sqlite, sequelize.js, migration, associations

I'm getting this error when I try to get a list of models with nested results using the "include" option with my model in Sequelize. The error says that the alias used on my association not exist. However I put the relation options with the alias on my models and the foreign key field in this case (in Note) is referenced correctly.

I'm using Sequelize with SQLite3.

[image: The output error from my console]

The error occurs when I use this code
[image]

This is my model User code

```
"use strict"
const { Model } = require("sequelize")
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class User extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.hasMany(models.Note, {
        foreignKey: "userId",
        as: "notes",
        sourceKey: "id",
        onDelete: "cascade",
      })
    }
  }
  User.init(
    {
      username: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        unique: true,
        allowNull: false,
      },
      password: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "User",
    }
  )
  return User
}
```

The code of my Note model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Note extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
      this.belongsTo(models.User, {
        as: "user",
        onDelete: "cascade",
      })
    }
  }
  Note.init(
    {
      title: DataTypes.STRING,
      content: DataTypes.TEXT,
      photo: DataTypes.STRING,
      userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        references: {
          model: "User",
          key: "id",
        },
      },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      modelName: "Note",
    }
  )
  return Note
}
```

Additionaly, I'm using sequelize-cli to create the models and the migrations, and I have a bulk of this data also generated with sequelize-cli. Bellow is the code.

```
await queryInterface.bulkInsert("Users", [
      {
        username: "user1",
        password: "password1",
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      },
      {
        username: "user2",
        password: "password2",
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      },
      {
        username: "user3",
        password: "password3",
        createdAt: new Date(),
        updatedAt: new Date(),
      },
    ])
```

```
await queryInterface.bulkInsert("Notes", [
  {
    title: "Note 1",
    content: "Content 1",
    photo: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    userId: 1,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    updatedAt: new Date(),
  },
  {
    title: "Note 2",
    content: "Content 2",
    photo: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    userId: 1,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    updatedAt: new Date(),
  },
  {
    title: "Note 3",
    content: "Content 3",
    photo: "https://picsum.photos/200/300",
    userId: 1,
    createdAt: new Date(),
    updatedAt: new Date(),
  },
])
```

I tried generating the association like the documentation says, and migrating using sequelize-cli. The tables are created with the fields correctly, the seed info are filling the db correctly and when I execute the method findAll all are running ok. The error occurs when I use the include parameter with the Model or with the alias. The association could be not built correctly.

Comment: Please add the code that actually causing the error.

Comment: Please show the code where you initialize models and their associations